# How to use Mockito to mock a class in a way that it passes javax validation

Tags: junit, mockito, javax.validation

Given a class:

```
public class Foo {

    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private Bar bar;    

    // plus getter/setter
}
```

Suppose I want to test that after the `bar` field is set, the class is now valid.

In my test, I'm using Mockito to get a fake `Bar` instance. I want this `mockBar` to be valid, without me having to worry about the particular field validations that `Bar` may contain.

Is there a Mockito way to make `mockBar` pass validation? Here's how I call validation in my test:

```
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
assertTrue(new ArrayList<>(validator.validate(foo)).isEmpty());
```

The `javax.validation.Validator` will recursively validate all fields of foo, so at some point the validator will do something with the `mockBar`. What do I need to mock to get this to return as valid?

Comment: I think you describing two conflicting requirements here. Either you want it to be valid, which means you need to take care of its fields values, or you don't want to validate it at all. But anyway, I'm interested if there is a solution to this :)

Comment: I want the class under test (`foo`) to be valid. I don't want to have to worry about the validity of the members of that class -- I want to simply declare them valid, because I can test the validity of `bar` in a different unit test.

Comment: If `Validator` implementation  internally used recursive calls for `@Valid` annotated embedded object you could spy on it and return empty List if type matches `Bar`. But this would be pretty brittle I'd say